# Basic drawing tools for .NET application

Tags: .net, drawing, bitmap, image

I need a control that allows loading a picture, performing some basic drawing tasks with it (including adding text, pencil, oval, horizontal and diagonal lines), and exporting it as bitmap.
Anything like that available?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made my own control based on Mouse_Down, Mouse_Up, and Mouse_Move events of PictureBox.

Answer (score 1):

[Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) is a good container for this task:

```
// Load the image from an existing file
using (var img = Image.FromFile("test.png"))
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
{
    // Scratch on it
    g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red, 10), new Point(0, 0), new Point(100, 100));
    g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Brushes.Black), 10, 10, 100, 100);
    g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Red), 30, 30, 40, 40);

    // Save to a new file
    img.Save("test2.png");
}
```

Comment: I expect that the OP wants a control which accepts user input, e.g. with a toolbar.

Comment: @ChrisW: probably, but it's not hard to cook a custom control up.

Comment: ChrisW: that's right, I need a control with toolbar. It's definitely possible to write it from scratch, but I thought maybe a solution exists already.

Answer (score 1):

Check this nice article about image processing: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/Image_Processing_Lab.aspx

And this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/Painter.aspx